# Hiding URL and date from printing header and footer while printing through IE browser

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the following css to hide printing header and footer which is working fine in chrome but not still print in IE.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <title>Print Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">

  @page :footer {color: #fff }
  @page :header {color: #fff}
        @page 
        {
            size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
            margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        }

        body 
        {
            background-color:#FFFFFF; 
            border: solid 1px black ;
            margin: 0px;  /* the margin on the content before printing */
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>Top line</div>
    <div>Line 2</div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Still page name and page count printing in header and page link and date printing in footer while printing through IE browser. Any specific code which can be used to hide while printing through IE browser. Kindly help in this.

Comment: Any one can help me please in hiding header and footer that print URL and data in print in IE specific

Comment: I don’t think that is possible for a website to specify using either CSS or JS in IE, the users have to explicitly configure this themselves on their end.